# HSTS max-age not effective/no update in Nginx

Tags: nginx

Using Debian10 and a fresh/new Nginx1.20.1, when I check:
`curl -I https://example.com` I get `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000` and when I check my website in  [`https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html`](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html), I see the result as

> Strict Transport Security (HSTS)  Yes   TOO SHORT (less than 180 days)
> max-age=2592000

I searched all my nginx.conf and all included files, but I can't find the directive `add_header Strict-Transport-Security ...`.

So, I added the following line to my server block, http block, location block, all of them, one of them , tested different cases:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=41536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
```

and again checked in the above link and the result was :

> Strict Transport Security (HSTS)  Invalid   Server provided more than one HSTS header

Good to say that, in both of the above cases, when I check response header in firefox browser, `max-age` is `2592000` and again my newly added directive does not come into effect!

I'm using cloudeflare as my DNS-server, so I enabled/disabled HSTS in my dashboard but no changes observed.

Let me now how could I find the default value of `Strict-Transport-Security max-age` in Nginx and how to change it effectively.

Comment: If it is from Nginx, it may be shown with the following command... `sudo nginx -T | grep -i Strict-Transport-Security`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My webApp is made by ASP.net core and it has a default value of 30 days for HSTS, when HTTPS was enabled in startup.cs. This made the nginx configurations to be tempted as duplication and some error in analyzers.

Answer (score 3):

Cloudflare is the TLS terminating endpoint that rest of the world sees. Therefore it sets the HSTS headers. The origin HSTS headers are ignored by Cloudflare.

You need to modify the HSTS settings in Cloudflare control panel.

Comment: Thank, but as i said in the question the problem is : `I'm using cloudeflare as my DNS-server, so I enabled/disabled HSTS in my dashboard but no changes observed`, I changed max-age and cleared everything in my browser and checked by curl and online-TSLcheckers, but always max-age is 2592000